# How to test stripe subscriptions in localhost?

Tags: stripe-payments

My code sets up stripe subscriptions (recurring charges) using the code given below

```
            $strtok = \Stripe\Token::create([
                     'card' => [
                     'number' => $ccNum,
                     'exp_month' => $expMonth,
                     'exp_year' => $expYear,
                     'cvc' => $cvc
                     ],
                   ]
             );
            $stripetoken = $strtok->id;
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
                   'source' => $stripetoken,
                   'email' => $email
             ]);
            $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
              'customer' => $customer->id,
              'plan' => $planId,
            ]);
```

If I understand correctly stripe first attempts to charge the card immediately after the subscription call. Is it absolutely necessary to set up a stripe web hook url to get the charge details like chargeId and so on? I mean I am working in the test mode and I am not in a position to set up a stripe web hook url pointing to a server. I want to get the stripe chargeId and other charge details when stripe first charges the card and also when stripe subsequently charges the card in periodic intervals for testing purposes. I want to do this in my local system which is in a local network connected to the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need webhooks here. The API request is synchronous which means that, after you call `\Stripe\Subscription::create()` Stripe will have tried to charge the customer already.

You would either get a `Subscription` [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object) back if the charge was successful or an [error](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) if not.

Assuming the charge succeeded, you can then immediately retrieve the latest charge and invoice via the API. The easiest is to retrieve one and use the [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) feature to get everything at once. Your code would become:

```
$invoices = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array(
    "limit" => 1,
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    "expand" => array("data.charge")
));

$invoice = $invoices->data[0];
$invoiceId = $invoice->id;
$chargeId = $invoice->charge->id;
```

As for webhooks locally you can always use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to automatically redirect events to localhost.

Comment: The above code would fetch me the first charge details as soon as the subscription is created. Thanks for the code. But I still have a problem. My server is ephemeral in nature. How do I fetch the charge details for the subsequent charges in subsequent months (for monthly subscriptions) without setting up a web hook? For that I have to use a tool like ngrok, is it? In order to use the above code every month, do I have to set up some kind of cron that executes a script? I am not sure if this is possible in the case of an amazon ec2 ephemeral server which I am planning to use later.

Comment: @jai ngrok is used to test webhooks locally, nothing else. You wouldn't use ngrok here, your code would be live on a server and would just always run. and whenever a new charge happens, the `invoice.payment_succeeded` event would be sent to your webhook endpoint and your code would handle the event and automatically update your database. This is all documented on Stripe's documentation for webhooks and subs: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks and https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/lifecycle

Comment: Can you tell me how to use ngrok with docker?

Comment: never tried but http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2015/01/tunnelling-docker-container-using-ngrok/ seems to cover what you need, I'd recommend checking this out or googling a bit and trying it on your end!

Answer (score 1):

koopajah is right: webhooks are not required to charge cards.
However for other payment sources (like SEPA debit for example), charges succeed asynchronously, after some hours/days. In such cases your program really needs to receive webhook events.

To receive events on `localhost`:

- You can redirect them using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) as suggested earlier.
- Or you can use a fake local Stripe server, running on `localhost`, like [localstripe](https://github.com/adrienverge/localstripe).
  Once installed and running, configure your PHP application to use localstripe instead of real Stripe servers:

  ```php
  \Stripe\Stripe::$apiBase = "http://localhost:8420";
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_abcdefgh");
  ```

  and configure localstripe to send events to your application. Assuming your PHP app listens for events on `localhost:1111/api/stripe`:

  ```sh
  curl localhost:8420/_config/webhooks/mywebhook1 \
    -d url=http://localhost:1111/api/stripe -d secret=whsec_yoursecret
  ```

Answer (score 0):

> I mean I am working in the test mode and I am not in a position to set up a stripe web hook url pointing to a server.

In general, you can go to a service like http://www.ip-adress.eu/ to first retrieve your public facing IP address (v4).

Then log on to your router (the address will be something like 192.168.X.Y which you can look up in your computer's network interface details)

Set up a port forwarding rule in your router, so that traffic to it on a particular port range will be directed to your computer (eg. `54764`).

Now have your localhost server running listening to the same port (`54764`).

Go to your Stripe dashboard and make sure you are in test mode.

Add a webhook URL for your IPv4 and port combination.

Now you should be able to test your local webserver externally without hosting your code somewhere during development.

(NOTE: this is not exclusive to Stripe, you can use this setup for speaking to a local webserver on your machine from any external endpoint)